# SonataAdmin custom datagrid filter template

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, sonata

In my CMS I need to have filter based on Date range, but I need to custom style it.

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add(
            'date',
            DateRangeFilter::class,
            [],
            DateRangePickerType::class
        );
    }
```

I need to custom style the whole widget, not just the inputs. I tried adding custom filter template to my config but it wouldn't work. Also tried adding ['attr' => ['class' => 'myClassName']] to field options, but I couldn't add class to the whole form row.

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    templates:
        filter:
            - CmsBundle:CRUD:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me.